# How to merge two arrays of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have two arrays of hashes:

```
a = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "foo"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: "baz"
  }
]

b = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "bar"
  },
  {
    key: 1000,
    value: "something"
  }
]
```

I want to merge them into one array of hashes, so essentially `a + b` except I want any duplicated key in `b` to overwrite those in `a`. In this case, both `a` and `b` contain a key `1` and I want the final result to have `b`'s key value pair.

Here's the expected result:

```
expected = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "bar"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: "baz"
  },
  {
    key: 1000,
    value: "something"
  }
]
```

I got it to work but I was wondering if there's a less wordy way of doing this:

```
hash_result = {}
a.each do |item|
  hash_result[item[:key]] = item[:value]
end

b.each do |item|
  hash_result[item[:key]] = item[:value]
end

result = []
hash_result.each do |k,v|
  result << {:key => k, :value => v}
end

puts result

puts expected == result # prints true
```

Comment: You want the functionality of a hash : you want unique keys and you want an easier way to merge your data. So just use hashes, as in @Ilya's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) would work if you concatenate the arrays in reverse order:

```
(b + a).uniq { |h| h[:key] }
#=> [
#     {:key=>1, :value=>"bar"},
#     {:key=>1000, :value=>"something"},
#     {:key=>2, :value=>"baz"}
#   ]
```

It doesn't however preserve the order.

Comment: This is the best.

Comment: Order isn't important with hashes.

Comment: @theTinMan `a` and `b` are arrays. Also, with ruby hashes order is preserved, and, hence, important.

Comment: No, order isn't important. Insertion order is preserved with a hash, but it's trivial to create a hash and extract values from it in any order desired. In many languages hashes do not maintain order, including previous versions of Ruby. Before hashes maintained that order everyone knew how to process them by ordering the keys.

Comment: @theTinMan: Python will soon have ordered dicts by default : https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/850102884972675072 . It's very convenient, so why not?

Answer (score 2):

```
[a, b].map { |arr| arr.group_by { |e| e[:key] } }
      .reduce(&:merge)
      .flat_map(&:last)
```

Here we use `hash[:key]` as a key to build the new hash, then we `merge` them overriding everything with the last value and return `values`.

Comment: `reduce(&:merge)` should be enough

Comment: @Ilya no ideas :) I do not care, though.

Comment: @mudasobwa dude why are you obfuscating the code, i think simply it would be `(b+a).group_by { |e| e[:key] }.values.map {|arr| arr.first}`

Comment: @aqfaridi the fact you have problems reading ruby code does not mean it is somehow obfuscated.

Comment: @mudasobwa buddy, i understood your code, but you are using map twice in single operation which makes it redundant operation, anyways no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would rebuild your data a bit, since there are redundant keys in hashes:

```
thin_b = b.map { |h| [h[:key], h[:value]] }.to_h
#=> {1=>"bar", 1000=>"something"}
thin_a = b.map { |h| [h[:key], h[:value]] }.to_h
#=> {1=>"bar", 1000=>"something"}
```

Then you can use just `Hash#merge`:

```
thin_a.merge(thin_b)
#=> {1=>"bar", 2=>"baz", 1000=>"something"}
```

But, if you want, you can get exactly result as mentioned in question:

```
result.map { |k, v| { key: k, value: v } }
#=> [{:key=>1, :value=>"bar"}, 
#    {:key=>2, :value=>"baz"}, 
#    {:key=>1000, :value=>"something"}]
```

Comment: That's not exactly what OP asked for but that's probably the best answer anyway. An alternative would be : `(a+b).each_with_object({}){ |s, h| h[s[:key]] = s[:value] }`

Answer (score 0):

using [Enumerable#group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) and [Enumerable#map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map)

```
(b+a).group_by { |e| e[:key] }.values.map {|arr| arr.first}
```